# What is the role of diagonalization in the proof of undecidability of the halting problem?

Tags: undecidability, halting-problem, diagonalization

I'm trying to understand the proof of undecidability of the halting problem. Some resources give a short proof based on a proof by contradiction. There is no mention of diagonalization. But some others also mention diagonalization in the proof. I'm rather confused about the role of diagonalization in this proof. Is it needed? If yes what is its role? Or can the proof be done without utilizing diagonalization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you found an unusual proof, they're all [refutations by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction#Refutation_by_contradiction) (not "proofs by contradiction", although that is common parlance) *and* they all are qlso a form of diagonalization: to refute the claim, we assume there were a halting oracle, and derive a contradiction by diagonalizing against the oracle.

You might be getting too hung up with what books *call* these proofs, and whether they bother to mention words "contradiction" and "diagonalization". They should all be the same proof, if we discount minor details in presentation.

Comment: For the problem "are there any functions that are not primitive recursive" it turned out that the Big Ackermann function provides the solution - it grows faster than any primitive recursive function can. It is conceivable that there might be a concrete function where for some reason halting cannot be determined. For example if the complexity of determining that P halts with input N grows so fast with N that no program can handle it.

Comment: You mean a concrete Turing machine, not a function, presumably. Anyhow, what you suggest has been studied. You can create a Turing machine whose halting problem is equivalent to consistency of a formal system (such as Peano arithmetic or Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory). To decide the halting of this particular machine, we need to trust consistency of a formal system that's even stronger (by Gödel incompleteness). However, there is no Turing machine whose halting problem is *absolutely* undecidable, irrespective of the ambient logic and axioms .

Comment: @AndrejBauer can you please explain why "they all are also a form of diagonalization"?

Comment: @SanyoMn: Alas, I cannot because you did not point to any specific proofs. Here is what I can do: you show me proofs of non-existence of the halting oracle, and I will explain why they are all the same proof, which takes the form of diagonalization. If you find a proof that is not, I owe you a beer (or a drink of your choice).

Comment: @AndrejBauer For example the proof given here: https://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/nelson/courses/csc_173/computability/undecidable.html

Comment: By diagonalization I assume something similar to Cantor's diagonalization argument . But I could not see something similar to it in the link I gave above.

Comment: Yes, the proof you pointed to is refutation by contradiction (it explicitly says "proof by contradiction" and proceeds to refute the claim by assuming it). It is a proof by diagonalization, specifically at one point is says "how about $\mathrm{OPP}(\mathrm{OPP})$?". This sort of self-application is a telltale sign that diagonalization is occuring.

(P.S. I do not recommend this proof. There are classic textbooks that do a much better job, but nothing beats [this video](https://youtu.be/92WHN-pAFCs?si=AuAx3JeBSB9SVVNb), which is also refutation by contradiction using diagonalization.)

Comment: I think the problem is with my understanding of diagonalization since I do not understand why "how about OPP(OPP)?" is a sign of diagonalization is occurring. Anyway, I will continue to look for better resources and definitely watch the interesting video you cited. Thanks.

Comment: The pures for of diagonalization appears in [Lawvere's fixed point theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere's+fixed+point+theorem), all the others are derivatives of this one. The "diagonalization" parts appears when a map $\phi : A \to B^A$ (see the link for details) is applied twice to the same argument, $\phi(p)(p)$. If you think about it, $\{(p,p) \mid p \in A\} \subseteq A \times A$ is the *diagonal* in the cartesian product $A \times A$, hence the name.

Comment: Here's [a description of Lawvere's diagonalization argument](https://math.andrej.com/2007/04/08/on-a-proof-of-cantors-theorem/) with category theory removed.